# Accessing Html/php file having Js inside it using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have one **index.php** from where i am accessing **noun_phrase.php** to return a variable. Now I have to pass the returned variable from **noun_phrase.php** to another php file **placeapi.php** to execute certain task.

**index.php**

```
if(dialog.indexOf("restaurant")!=-1 ){

       $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
       showText="";
       sayText="";
       $.ajax({
       url: "noun_phrase.php",
       data: {text: dialog},
       success: function(data) {
       nlp = data;
       findPlace(nlp);

}
       });
       }

       function findPlace(x){
           name = x;
           $.ajax({
               url: "placeapi.php",
               data: {text: name},
               success: function (data){

               }
           });
       }
```

**placeapi.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Place searches</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
  }
  </style>


  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCmrjT6f4nt15qV-L9MRWL43TgucZzJHCw
 &libraries=places"></script>

  <script>
 var map;
 var infowindow;
 function initialize() {
     var city = new google.maps.LatLng(-42.882391,147.328591);
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
  center: city,
  zoom: 15
  });
  var request = {
      location: city,
  radius: 500,
  types: ['hotel']
  };
 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
 }

 function callback(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
         for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
             createMarker(results[i]);
         }
  }
 }
 function createMarker(place) {
     var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: place.geometry.location
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map-canvas">

  </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

*I want to pass a data retrieved from **noun_phrase.php** to javaScript function of **placeapi.php** and get location so that i can display somewhere*

Answer (score 0):

You simply echo the value inside the constructor `google.maps.LatLng`

```
 function initialize() {
         var city = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_POST['latitude'] ?>,<?php echo $_POST['latitude'] ?>); 
// longitude and latitude are part of `npl`
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: city,
      zoom: 15
      });
      var request = {
          location: city,
      radius: 500,
      types: ['hotel']
      };
```

Ensure your add `method:POST` in your ajax

Comment: Well, i tried this and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access through javascript then send a get request to `noun_phrase.php`.
And echo or return the response from `noun_phrase.php`
And get this response from `placeapi.php`